# what is the transcription of the following audios?

Tags: translation, meaning, transcription

I need the japanese transcription of the following audios...
[audio 1](http://vocaroo.com/i/s0KSZkDBJmtH) and [audio 2](http://vocaroo.com/i/s0u5UBXweNa0). These audios are part of the anime Holy Knight (OVA).

Context: a vampire girl is captured by the opposing side.

I understand most of it, but I fail to understand what is in brackets...

Audio 1:

> 糟{かす}は命を与えれて現世{げんせい}には[...]なんて信じたくないはなしだ。
>
> 神は[**もえこと**]なさる。 (what this part mean?)

Audio 2:

> いいね… その喋{しゃべ}りかた… ごみはひっしに[...]しないと生き残れないものね。

Others links:
[Audio 1](https://clyp.it/24u2dlro)
[Audio 2](https://clyp.it/jpw5gohk)

Comment: I believe the blank in Audio 2 is 奉仕, probably telling the girl to "service" the man. No idea about Audio 1 - probably have to see the episode itself to get more context information.

Comment: I also think it is 奉仕.

Comment: Both audio pages say "Sorry, the requested media could not be found. It may have expired or been deleted."

Comment: It's strange, I can play the audio. I put other links just in case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the dialogs in the last ten minutes of *Holy Knight OVA* vol.2. Your transcription is almost correct.

> いいね……その喋り方……ごみは必死に**奉仕**しないと生き残れないものね。
>
> カス**が**命を与えられて現世【げんせ】に**まで生きてる**なんて信じたくない話だ。神は**むごいこと**をなさる。

The consonant //g// in the middle of word is normally reduced to [[[ɣ]]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_velar_fricative), which I guess you tend to fail to detect.